# Summation of third column for inverse pair of columns

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file with three columns. I am trying to sum up the values in the third column when inverse pair of columns exist. My file looks like this;

```
200 297 3.0%
57 55 40.1%
57 56 16.5%
55 57 59.9%
56 57 83.5%
```

I want to sum the third column when `[$1, $2] = [$2, $1]` and reduce the file by keeping the sum of their percentages. 
So what I finally expect to get is;

```
200 297 3.0%
57 55 100%
57 56 100%
```

I am not an expert of awk, but I tried to modify few codes that I found in here and tried to optimize for may case, but didn't get what I expected.

I have tried

```
awk '{tmp1=$1 $2; tmp2=$2 $1; if(tmp1 in arr || tmp2 in arr) {next} arr[$1 $2] +=$3} END {for(i in arr) { print arr[i]}}' infile > outfile
```

Also have tried

```
awk ' ! Pairs[$1, $2] {Pairs[$1, $2] = Pairs[$2, $1] += $3; print $0 } ' infile > outfile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '{sub("%","",$NF); 
        if( ($2 FS $1) in a) a[$2 FS $1]+=$3; 
        else a[$1 FS $2]=$3} END{for(k in a) print k, a[k]"%"}' file

200 297 3.0%
57 55 100%
57 56 100%
```

there may be a simpler way...

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '(($2,$1) in a){a[$2,$1]+=$3+0;next}{a[$1,$2]=$3+0} END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]"%"}}' SUBSEP=" "  Input_file
```

Comment: Did you get downvoted? I think @jww has been up to his usual shenanigans this morning.

Comment: @EdMorton, no Ed sir as of now I haven't got, I will up-vote you now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '
    { val[$1>$2 ? $1 OFS $2 : $2 OFS $1] += $3 }
    END { for (key in val) print key, val[key]"%" }
' file
297 200 3%
57 55 100%
57 56 100%
```

Comment: Sir, can you please [edit] your post and add some explanation?

Comment: @Shashanth sure but it's 2 lines of idiomatic awk that's been seen in hundreds of posts in this forum alone and employs **the** approach to this problem that's also seen in hundreds of programs in dozens of other languages. What part of it do you not understand?